# Erlang Matrix Library

Tags: matrix, erlang, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking for a robust library to handle matrices in Erlang. Nothing fancy, just efficient handling of multiplication and basic operations. I could do that with lists etc. but I'm sure my implementation won't be very efficient !

Comment: I'm sure the folks at http://www.wings3d.com must be doing these kinds of things.  Maybe you could have a grovel in the source code there to see what they are doing?

Comment: @spong Your comment is as good as an answer.

Comment: @Pindatjuh probably only qualifies as half an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presentation in this link talks about some erlang bindings to BLAS etc - 
[High Performance Technical Computing in Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/workshop/2008/Sess23.pdf). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The linked document is missing.